# Возврат данных EF Core в методе

Tags: entity-framework-core, c#-8.0

Наверно я изобретаю велосипед с квадратными колесами(возможно есть более элегантное решение).Мне нужно, что бы метод возвращал список всех объектов которые были объеденены по нескольким таблицам:

```
  public List<Address> GetAddress()
    {
        using (var db = new CrmDbContext())
        {
            var address = from a in db.Addresses
                          join City in db.Cities on a.CityId equals City.CityId
                          join Area in db.Areas on a.AreaId equals Area.AreaId
                          select a;
  
            List<Address> result = address.ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Если я вывожу так:

```
foreach(var address in addressModel.GetAddress())
 {
     WriteLine(address.City.CityName);
 }
```

То у меня вылетает Ecxeption

System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Скорей всего я зря так делаю.
Но хотелось бы хранить метод по выводу объектов(например адрессов) в отдельном классе и выводить через метод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему вы не хотите использовать методы `Linq`? Для примера, представим, что у вас есть таблица `UserEntity`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Login { get; set; }
```

И таблица телефонов `PhoneEntity`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Объединим это всё связью `один-ко-многим`. `UserEntity`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Login { get; set; }

public ICollection<PhoneEntity> Phones { get; set; }
```

И сам телефон `PhoneEntity`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }

public int UserId { get; set; }
public UserEntity User { get; set; }
```

Как теперь это всё вытянуть и привязать к `UserEntity` все его телефоны `PhoneEntity`:

```
var users = _dbContext.Users.Include(user => user.Phones).ToList();
```

Тут мы используем `.Include()`, который аналогичный использованию `LEFT JOIN`

Далее представим, что у вас к телефону ещё привязана книга контактов (`PhoneEntity` -> `ContactEntity` как `one-to-many`), тогда запрос, который объеденит это всё будет выглядеть вот так:

```
var users = _dbContext.Users
    .Include(user => user.Phones)
        .ThenInclude(phone => phone.Contacts)
    .ToList();
```

Далее для примера, мы можем изменить нашего UserEntity сделующим образом:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Login { get; set; }

public ICollection<PhoneEntity> Phones { get; set; }
public ICollection<DocumentEntity> Documents { get; set; }
```

Как нам вытянуть все данные вместе? Вот так:

```
var users = _dbContext.Users
    .Include(user => user.Phones)
        .ThenInclude(phone => phone.Contacts)
    .Include(user => user.Documents)
    .ToList();
```

Далее всё по аналогии. Это замечательная аналогия тому, что вы хотите.

**P.S.**: Я не писал прямой ответ на ваш вопрос, а лишь предоставил информацию для того, что бы вы разобрались с этими понятиями и смоги самостоятельно выучить этот материал и решить задачу

**UPD:** если вы хотите сделать выборку, используйте метод `.Where()`, вот пример использования для последнего примера кода:

```
var users = _dbContext.Users
    .Where(user => user.Id > 100)
    .Include(user => user.Phones)
        .ThenInclude(phone => phone.Contacts)
        .Where(phone => phone.Phone != "1234567890")
    .Include(user => user.Documents)

    .ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли.

Comment: @Ildar , если ответ помог, отметьте, пожалуйста, решением

Answer (score 1):

`Linq` по умолчанию делает "ленивую" выборку, не включая в результат значения из связанных таблиц. Нужно прямо указать, какие поля выборки, указывающие на другие таблицы, вы хотите загрузить, с помощью метода `Include`. Например, как это приведено в другом ответе через "объектный" стиль и "дот-нотацию".

Но, насколько я понял из [ответа на английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6776439/8324991), `Include` можно использовать и с вашим `sql`-стилем запросов. Так должно сработать:

```cs
var address = (from a in db.Addresses
              join City in db.Cities on a.CityId equals City.CityId
              join Area in db.Areas on a.AreaId equals Area.AreaId
              select a).Include("City");
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ загружаем в поле связанные значения
```

Comment: Спасибо этот вариант буду иметь ввиду. Он проще всего. Но я выбрал вариант выше.

Comment: @Ildar И это правильно. ООП не зря придумали, лучше всё делать в явном виде на объектах. )